# Tbmp Skeleton toolbar

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, toolbar

This is a really strange question but I haven't been able to figure this out.

How do I remove the `toolbar` in `Tbmp Skeleton`? I don't see it anywhere.

`Tbmp Skeleton` is part of the downloads available from `Google Play Game Services`.

I've checked everywhere but see no trace of a toolbar. I wonder if the `Google Developers` created the `toolbar` in a special way.

Any ideas?

Comment: yes, it is strange ... you are trying build the app with google play services without  android's basic knowledge ... toolbar "is" in theme used for Activity

Comment: hm so how can I remove it?

Comment: hmmm change the theme and select the one without actionbar ...

Comment: for example `android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar`

Comment: Ha thanks. fixed it...i feel like an idiot haha. so...want to help me finish my multiplayer game ;)

Comment: you shouldn't ... just really start from some basics ... guide on d.android.com is really good